# C# async task completes before it's finished

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm developing a network application that receives data from a websocket, modifies it, and uploads it to a data service. Uploading the data takes some time and I'd like to hide that latency, uploading several messages at once. When an upload is complete I need to send an acknowledgement back through the websocket.

I've created a work queue to hold all of the outstanding tasks. This seems to be working well, so I haven't included it. But my upload task appears to be finishing before it's actually finished. Here's a trimmed down sample.

```
private async Task UploadDataAsync(string data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task uploadTask = new Task(async () =>
    {
        // Simulates uploading data
        await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
    });

    _ = uploadTask.ContinueWith(async (t1) =>
    {
        // Clean up the task
        await RemoveTask(t1);

        if (t1.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            await SendAck(this, data, cancellationToken);
        else if (t1.IsFaulted)
            logger.LogError(t1.Exception, $"An error occurred while uploading {data}");
        else if (t1.IsCanceled)
            logger.LogWarning($"An upload task {data} was canceled");

    }, TaskScheduler.Default);

    await AddTask(uploadTask);
    uploadTask.Start();
}
```

In the preceding code the acknowledgement is sent before the data is uploaded. Surprisingly this seems to be because my Task uses an async lambda. For a reason I don't understand `uploadTask` completes when the upload is awaited. So I changed it to something like this:

```
private async Task UploadDataAsync(string data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task uploadTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        // Simulates uploading data
        Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken).Wait();
    });

    _ = uploadTask.ContinueWith((t1) =>
    {
        // Clean up the task
        RemoveTask(t1).Wait();

        if (t1.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            SendAck(this, data, cancellationToken).Wait();
        else if (t1.IsFaulted)
            logger.LogError(t1.Exception, $"An error occurred while uploading {data}");
        else if (t1.IsCanceled)
            logger.LogWarning($"An upload task {data} was canceled");

    }, TaskScheduler.Default);

    await AddTask(uploadTask);
    uploadTask.Start();
}
```

Now everything executes in the correct order, except when things go wrong or the operation is canceled (e.g. the server is shutdown). Now I'm dealing with AggregateExceptions and TaskCanceledExceptions.

This seems like it should be easier than I'm making it. Am I doing this wrong?

**Edit** Adding pseudocode that calls `UploadDataAsync` for context.

```
protected override async Task DoConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (_websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Simulates getting websocket data
        string result = await _websocket.ReceiveAsync();

        // This should only asynchronously wait for the upload task to get
        // created. It should not wait for the upload to complete.
        await OnDataReceived(result, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually await `uploadTask`? What do you do in `AddTask`?

Comment: Add uploadTask.Wait() in the end of your first code.

Comment: @HirasawaYui [Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @HirasawaYui In general, it's a bad idea to mix `await` and `.Wait()` in C# - you should use one or the other. Otherwise, it'll deadlock under most circumstances (see the linked article).

Comment: "Rather than calling this constructor, the most common way to instantiate a Task object and launch a task is by calling the static `Task.Run(Action)` or `TaskFactory.StartNew(Action)` method.... The constructor should only be used in advanced scenarios where it is required that the creation and starting of the task is separated." [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica The uploadTask is placed into a list. It executes completely in parallel. There could be many of these upload tasks executing in parallel each time the websocket server gets some data. AddTask waits on a semaphore and adds the task to a list.

Comment: @HirasawaYui That would block the caller until the upload is finished, wouldn't it? The point is that the upload is completely in parallel.

Comment: @JohnWu I have to add the task to a work queue. That's why I create it and then start it later. If the websocket connection (not shown) is stopped I make sure all the upload tasks are completed before shutting down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `Task` constructor having an async delegate is that the signature of the delegate is resolved to [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) instead of `async Task`, so the asynchronous operation cannot be awaited (`async void` is useful mainly for event handlers, and harmful in most other cases). This happens because the `Task` constructor does not understand async delegates, meaning that it has no overload that accepts a `Func<Task>` argument.

There is a way to solve this problem without removing the `Task` constructor from your solution, although its usage is frowned upon by the experts. Instead of a non-generic `Task` you can use a generic [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1), with the `TResult` being a `Task`. In other words you can use a nested `Task<Task>`. The job of the outer task is to create the inner task, by executing the supplied async delegate. This is a CPU-bound operation that in most cases will have a very small duration. Essentially the outer task completes as soon as the code hits the first `await`¹ of the async delegate, and the rest of the work (that includes the high latency I/O operation) is represented by the inner task.

```
Task<Task> uploadTaskFactory = new Task<Task>(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken); // Simulates an I/O operation
});

//...
uploadTaskFactory.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
Task uploadTask = await uploadTaskFactory; // takes essentially zero time

//...
await uploadTask; // takes 5 seconds
```

As you see using the `Task<Task>` constructor with an async delegate becomes rather awkward, so in general any alternative method should be preferred (especially when writing application code, for libraries it's okayish IMHO). Alternatives include the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) that does understand async delegates, or, if you don't want to start the task immediately, to pass around `Func<Task>`s and invoke them at the right moment.

¹ <sub>To be precise: the first `await` of a non-completed awaitable.</sub>

Comment: I reworked the whole answer because the original one was incorrect, and the code would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you call `uploadTask.Start()` and just continue without ever waiting for it to finish. (Even `AddTask` happens *before* you call `uploadTask.Start()`). You should await `uploadTask` rather than just launching it and moving on right away.

Comment: The point is that this would execute in parallel. The caller should be able to continue, so awaiting would stop the caller from continuing until the data is uploaded.