# C# - Can multiple tasks running in parallel append to a string?

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, task

My string is empty when all the work is completed.  Any solution for that?

```
string jsonString = "";
List<Task> tasksToWait = new List<Task>();

// ...

foreach (string blah in blahs)
{
    counter++;

    // ...
    
    Task task = new Task(async () =>
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(baseURL + URLparams);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        jsonString += responseBody + ",";
    });

    task.Start();
    tasksToWait.Add(task);

    if (counter == 50)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasksToWait.ToArray());
        tasksToWait.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

In an effort to speed things up, I am kicking off multiple API requests at once rather than wait for one at a time.  Open to other options/solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why use `new Task` at all, given `HttpClient` is _already_ async?

Comment: The reason the string is empty is because by using the `Task` constructor with an async lambda you end up with an [async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) lambda that can't be awaited. To fix this problem you must either use a `Task<Task>` constructor, or preferably the handy `Task.Run`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659668/c-sharp-async-task-completes-before-its-finished/60664869#60664869) for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest creating the tasks then `await`ing them all with `Task.WhenAll` then use `string.Join`

They will be in the same order as they are in the list.

> If none of the tasks faulted and none of the tasks were canceled, the
> resulting task will end in the RanToCompletion state. The Result of
> the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the
> results of the supplied tasks **in the same order as they were provided**

```
public async Task<string> DoStuff(string data)
{
   var response = await _client.GetAsync("");
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   ...
   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var blahs = new List<string>();

var results = await Task.WhenAll(blahs.Select(DoStuff));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",results));
```