# await on task to finish, with operations after the 'await'

Tags: c#, async-await

I know I may be downvoted but apparently I just don't understand async-await enough and the questions/answer I found, and the articles I found, didn't help me to find an answer for this question:

How can I make "2" to be printed out? Or actually, WHY doesn't 2 gets printed out, both in await t and in t.Wait() ?:

```
static Task t;
public static async void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    t = GenerateTask();     
    await t;
    //t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}

public static Task GenerateTask()
{
    var res = new Task(async () => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("2"); 
    });
    res.Start();
    return res;
}
```

Edit:  I'm creating a task and returning it cause in real-life I need to await on this task later on, from a different method.

Edit2: await Task.Delay is just a placeholder for a real-life await on a different function.

Comment: You may want to check out the valid signatures of the [`Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) entry point, in order to [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: Related: [C# async task completes before it's finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659668/c-sharp-async-task-completes-before-its-finished)

Comment: [Never use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's because the constructor to new Task only takes some form of an Action (So the Task never gets returned even though it's async). So essentially what you're doing is an Async void with your delegate. Your `await Task.Delay(10000)` is returning and the action is considered 'done'.

You can see this if you change the `await Task.Delay(10000)` to `Task.Delay(10000).Wait()` and remove the async from the delegate.

On another note though, I've never personally seen or used new Task before. `Task.Run()` is a much more standard way to do it, and it'll allow for the await to be used. Also means you don't have to call Start() yourself.

Also you might already know this but, in this specific case you don't need a new task at all. You can just do this:

```
    public static async Task GenerateTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
```

---

**Regarding your edits**

Replacing your `GenerateTask` with what I wrote should do what you want. The async/await will turn your method into a Task that has started execution. This is exactly what you are trying to do so I'm not quite sure what you are asking with your edits.

The task returned from `GenerateTask` can be awaited whenever you want, or not awaited at all. You should almost never need to do `new Task()`. The only reason I can think is if you wanted to delay execution of the task until later, but there would be better ways around it rather than calling `new Task()`.

If you use the way I showed in your real-life situation, let me know what doesn't work about it and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks, I added some edits to my question. So how should I modify my code so that I'll await some function (instead of the Task.Delay) AND run some other code, all this wrapped in a Task, so I could await on it later on?

Comment: @Alonzzo2 I updated my reply with a response to your edits. I don't think I fully understand your use case, so I might need some more details if I didn't answer you.

Comment: You are right, what you (and @tymtam) suggested works, and is actually the first thing I tried. Imagine my surprise it didn't work: 1st reason is cause I tried it in an online compiler (.net fiddle) which didn't 'wait' the 10 seconds for the 2nd output. didn't think that would happen. 2nd reason is I guess there's another bug in my 'real-life' code

Answer (score 6):

## Printing '2'

The 2 is actually printed, 10 seconds after 1 is printed. You can observe this if you add `Console.ReadLine();` after printing 'Finished'.

The output is

```
Hello World
1
Finished
2
```

## What is happening?

When you await `t` (which is `res` in `GenerateTask` method) you are awaiting the created Task and not the task that `res` created.

## How to fix (fancy way)

You will need to await both the outer task and inner task. To be able to await the inner task you need to expose it. To expose it you need to change the type of the task from `Task` to `Task<Task>` and the return type from `Task` to `Task<Task>`.

It could look something like this:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    var outerTask = GenerateTask();     
    var innerTask = await outerTask; // what you have 
    await innerTask;                 // extra await
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static Task<Task> GenerateTask() // returns Task<Task>, not Task
{
    var res = new Task<Task>(async () => // creates Task<Task>, not Task
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Console.WriteLine("2"); 
    });
    res.Start();
    return res;
}
```

The output now is:

```
Hello World
1
2
Finished
```

## How to fix (easy way)

The outer task is not needed.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    var t  = GenerateTask();     
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static async Task GenerateTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    Console.WriteLine("2"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Task.Run()` rather than creating a `Task` directly:

```
public static Task GenerateTask()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    });
}
```

`Task.Start()` doesn't work because it doesn't understand async delegates, and the returned task just represents the beginning of the task.

Note that you can't fix this by using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` either, for the same reason.

See [Stephen Cleary's blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) on this issue, from which I quote:

> [Task.Factory.StartNew()] Does not understand async delegates. This is actually the same as
> point 1 in the reasons why you would want to use StartNew. The problem
> is that when you pass an async delegate to StartNew, it’s natural to
> assume that the returned task represents that delegate. However, since
> StartNew does not understand async delegates, what that task actually
> represents is just the beginning of that delegate. This is one of the
> first pitfalls that coders encounter when using StartNew in async
> code.

These comments also apply to the `Task` constructor, which also doesn't understand async delegates.

However, it's important to note that if you are already awaiting in the code and you don't need to parallelise some compute-bound code, you don't need to create a new task at all - just using the code in your `Task.Run()` on its own will do.